# H2 + Hibernate with non nullable String stores empty string

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I'm currently migrating some existing code from Hibernate 3.2 to Hibernate 3.6.10.Final
(and also from Spring 2.0 to Spring 3.1.2 by the way).

I have an issue with some integration tests running against H2 database, verifying that some fields are not nullable.
- I test that an attempt to insert a null String into a field marked as nullable=false ends with an Exception
- I checked that the schema is correctly created : the column is not nullable.

- Using H2 (with MySQL mode), nullable constraint is ignored : an empty String is inserted in database.
- I don't reproduce the case if I run my test against a MySQL database.
- It worked before with Hibernate 3.2

For example, if I have a class Person :

```
@Entity
class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    //getters and setters

}
```

And then I have a test (still using JUnit3, I'll migrate this later) :

```
@ExpectedException(value=DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public void testPerson_NameCantBeNull() throws Exception {
    // Given
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName(null);

    // When
    getHibernateTemplate().persist(person);
    //Flush and clear session
}
```

I could fix this by replacing nullable=false by `@NotNull` annotation but I don't want to replace it in my huge code base as I wouldn't expect the same Exception.
I had a quick look into H2Dialect class and JIRA issues in Hibernate but I didn't find anything.

Does anybody know where it comes from ?

EDIT :
Some additional informations, I added the TRACE level in Hibernate logs.

- When I insert null and the field is marked with `@Column(nullable=false)`, I have the following log :
  2013-01-16 15:57:52 TRACE [BasicExtractor] found **[]** as column [NAME1_3_]
- When I insert null and the field is **not marked** with `@Column(nullable=false)`, I have the following log :
  2013-01-16 15:57:52 TRACE [BasicExtractor] found **[null]** as column [NAME1_3_]

EDIT (22/01/13) :

I still didn't found where the problem exactly come from, but I found out that it is tied to MySQL mode with H2 : if I disable MySQL mode, Hibernate doesn't try anymore to replace my null Strings by empty Strings.
But I can't do this since some other pieces of code are tied to MySQL syntax.

Any idea ?

Comment: Some databases (Oracle is an example, IIRC) treat an empty string as a null value - others don't. It sounds like H2 doesn't. Certainly in Java itself the two are very different - do you have any reason to believe that H2 *does* view an empty string as a null value?

Comment: Sounds like MySQL acts like Oracle here: "In SQL NULL represents the the absence of a value. In MySQL an explicit NULL may also represent the next value of a pseudo-sequence and an implicit NULL may represent an implicit default value (a zero or empty string) determined by MySQL." (From http://sql-info.de/mysql/gotchas.html)

Comment: In fact, I have the inverse issue : I'm testing an insert with a null String (with Hibernate) and it ends as an empty String in the database so no exception occurs.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the test. Right. And there's no constructor which sets the name to an empty string to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have enough time to digg in Hibernate and MySQL dialect, so I moved to Java Validation Framework, using @NotNull annotation.

It does the job and meets one of our other requirement : a part of our model is used in a Grails application and we want to use constraints to validate part of CRUD operations (not possible with pure javax.persistence annotations).